# CICD on GCP for Firebase Functions failing due to "replace /workspace/.runtimeconfig.json?" error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have CICD for cloud functions as some of the functions require token (collection deletion), my pipeline takes care of that.

Since last release, the cloud build is failing to deploy functions as it's expecting some key press which can't be done during cloud build. The actual log error says the following:

"replace /workspace/.runtimeconfig.json? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: NULL"

Locally I am able to run the Cloud Functions with Node 14, but on GCP I'm not able to find a fix for GCP Cloud Build.

**Note: **

- I'm using latest packages as of today. firebase-tools package: 9.4.0
- There are similar questions for deploying functions locally but none of them work for me as it's during Cloud Build. I'm using the guide here: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase

  - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3120
  - [Firebase Functions deploy requires keyboard input in GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65950774/firebase-functions-deploy-requires-keyboard-input-in-gcp)

Comment: I am running into the same problem

Comment: I am also running into the same problem

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65950774/firebase-functions-deploy-requires-keyboard-input-in-gcp

It's fixed in firebase-tools v9.4.0 for x64 node binaries, but isn't working on M1 macs running arm binaries for node

Comment: @Kiana It's still not working for me. Note: Functions are getting deployed locally. My question is specific to GCP Cloud Build.

Comment: Can you check which versions of firebase-tools and crc32-stream you are using?  You can also follow github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3120 for updates.

Comment: @Kiana read my answer below. The issue was not my local version but which version GCP build was using. By default it uses latest Node Docker image, unless specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answers on other links mentioned above were correct indeed. What I didn't realize was that Docker image of node during build takes the latest automatically. Thus, now it was taking Node 15.xx version.

To fix this, just update Node version in the cloudbuild.yaml. For example following during npm install on GCP:

```
- name: node:14
  entrypoint: npm
  waitFor: ['-']
  id: 'npm-install'
  dir: 'functions'
  args: ['install']
```